# What if two boxers refused to fight each other?

Tags: rules, boxing, mma, martial-arts

Suppose that two boxers (or MMA fighters or similar) chose not to fight. They do nothing and persist in doing nothing even when instructed to start fighting.

Now if it was just one doing so, then he would either be attacked and knocked out, pinned, scored lower than his opponent, or otherwise determined to be the losing fighter.

But what if both fighters were doing the same, refusing to fight? Would it be a double loss? How is that decided?

Answer (score 3):

[The rules of boxing vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction...](http://boxrec.com/media/index.php/Rules_of_Boxing).

The most important thing is they are in the ring to fight, not to do nothing. If they don't engage in fighting, they will be given a warning or two. If they continue to do nothing after the warning, they will be disqualified.

I have never seen any situation like that in the past and I am 100% certain that it will never happen.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened in MMA, in the infamously known as "Detroit Dance", a match between Dan Severn and Ken Shamrock at UFC 9.

In the end, judges scored the match for Dan Severn and nothing much happened.

[This article](https://www.bloodyelbow.com/2013/2/4/3951260/ufc-history-severn-vs-shamrock-2-what-really-happened-at-ufc-9) explaining the reasons is funnier than the match itself.

Comment: While interesting, this doesn't answer the question: what happens if they totally refuse to fight? As it neither involves total refusal nor explains the consequence for doing so.